# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Earth Science's [moderator election](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates, we simply appointed the sole candidate:

[image: luser droog]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Comment: Congrats farrenthorpe!